# "TypeError: 'list' does not support the buffer interface" when writing bytes to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-data

I get the error `TypeError: 'list' does not support the buffer interface` when trying to run the following:

```
file = open(filename + ".bmp", "rb")
data = file.read()
file.close()
new = []

for byte in data:
    byte = int(byte)
    if byte%2:#make even numbers odd
        byte -= 1
    new.append(bin(byte))

file = open(filename + ".bmp", "wb")
file.write(new)
file.close()
```

Why is this happening? I think it is due to the data type I am writing to the `.bmp` but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you've read the file, `data` is a `bytes` object, which can behave like a list of numbers, but isn't one, while `new` is an actual list of numbers. Binary files support writing only bytes, so that's what you need to give it.

One solution is to replace `file.write(new)` with `file.write(bytes(new))`.

And here is a shorter rewrite of the code:

```
with open(filename+'.bmp', 'rb') as in_file:
    data = in_file.read()

new_data = bytes(byte//2*2 for byte in data)

with open(filename+'.bmp', 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(new_data)
```

Note that the BMP format contains some headers, not just pixel data, so it will probably become corrupt after such modification.

Comment: Thanks! I an aware of the headers (the first 14 bytes are metadata) and I plan to modify it when I can get the main part of the load-modify-save system working.

Comment: After some testing, it works if I convert an `integer` into a `bytes` object but NOT if I try to convert `binary` to `bytes`.